# Refresh expired token in apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

i am trying to refresh the access token once its expired
here is my code

```
const getNewTokens = () => {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('account:refreshToken');
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('account:accessToken');
    return apolloClient
      .mutate({
        mutation: REFRESH_TOKEN,
        variables: { accessToken, refreshToken }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const { tokens } = response.data.refreshTokens;
        localStorage.setItem('account:refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken);
        localStorage.setItem('account:accessToken', tokens.accessToken);
        return tokens;
      });
  };

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors)
      graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
        console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`)
      );
    if (networkError) {
      console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
      if (networkError.statusCode === 401) {
        getNewTokens().then(() => {
          const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;

          // modify the operation context with a new token
          operation.setContext({
            headers: {
              ...oldHeaders,
              authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('account:accessToken')}`
            }
          });

          // retry the request, returning the new observable
          return forward(operation);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

now what happens is when i get 401 Unauthorized, the refreshToken mutation returns the new tokens but it doesn't refetch the failed operation